# Iterating json array

Tags: json

Can anybody suggest a way to iterate the json array of format using jquery in javascript.

```
{"0",{"id":"10", "class": "child-of-9"},"1",{"id":"11", "class": "child-of-10"}}
```

i need to get the value of each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point have an **object** where the keys are *numbers*. This is effectively how an **array** works with it's indexes. What you have there is an **object**, not an **array**.

Turn this:

```
a = {"0",{"id":"10", "class": "child-of-9"},"1",{"id":"11", "class": "child-of-10"}}
```

Into this:

```
a = [{"id":"10", "class": "child-of-9"},{"id":"11", "class": "child-of-10"}]
```

And you have an *array of objects*. This can be iterated with a simple for loop, and accessed by index.

```
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  console.log(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You json is not correct. It should look more like

```
{"0": {"id":"10", "class": "child-of-9"},"1": {"id":"11", "class": "child-of-10"}};
```

Once it does you can use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over it.

```
    var data = {"0": {"id":"10", "class": "child-of-9"},"1": {"id":"11", "class": "child-of-10"}};
    jQuery.each( data, function(i,a){
        console.log(a['class']);
    });
```

By the way your json is not an array it is an object. To build the array version it would look like

```
[{"id":"10", "class": "child-of-9"},{"id":"11", "class": "child-of-10"}]
```